# why see all mobile tasks in Log section in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I was asking why I see all tasks in **logcat** where I need search only for my application's **log** error or info

Comment: you need to filter for your application only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use de logcat, by default it shows all tasks, so you can have all the possible information of the tasks that are running on, system's message, stack trace and what you set with log class. It's more like a help for the developer.

If you want to make a filter use a tag.

[image]

Then put the log where you want to see the error info, when the app runs it will show the regular logcat with all the tasks

[image]

So, to filter and look for your error info set the tag name like this[image]

**Edit**

you can see if some dependency did'nt work fine or some system message so you can see the time of your process to run.

[image]

Comment: ok thanks, but why may android studio show all tasks is there any uses i can make with them?

Comment: Sure, you can see if some dependency did'nt work fine or some system message so you can see the time of your process to run. All this is in order to help the dev. But this is more understandable when you have certain ammount of time using android studio, it's like a little bit complex when you are starting in this world believe me :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You have to chose selected application, or search on your log in search bar!

**For Example**:

```
Log.e(TAG, "MainActivity LOG " );
```

you have to search on

> MainActivity LOG

Comment: I know this I just need to know why may something like this appear
in other words is there way we use these tasks ?

Comment: cuz the log show you all process that is running on the device, you might be interested in one of this process later :)

Comment: like what? 
what I may use if I need only search for mine ?

Comment: for example you might interested in quality of something, or how much time thread take, etc..